# Creating a true/false column to indicate partial word matches between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

New to excel. I have tried using the VLOOKUP and IF function to find the best solution. However, I am struggling to get the partial match aspect down. I also want the partial match to include any spaces after the words.

Example

```
Column1  Column2    Column3
dog      cat        No Match
house    house(big) Match
cat      cat        Match
```

I have tried using the trim, VLOOKUP, and IF functions.

Comment: so, you need "partial Match" as a result of comparing house and house(big)?

Answer (score 2):

use SEARCH:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need "partial Match" as a result of comparing house and house(big)

```
=IF(A2=B2, "Match", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2, B2)), "Partial Match", "No Match"))
```